# Firewall with domain based rules for client

Tags: firewall

I want to set domain based firewall rules to a client (not all clients). Are there any firewall applications that support this? I basically want to be able block everything and add exceptions. With all the cloud hosting this is becoming increasingly difficult to do with just IP-based rules.

Needs to work on Windows 10. Mac OS X options would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to configure the firewall rule of domain profile on the remote machine(windows server, DC)?

Why not use the GPO on the Domain Controller, if for the windows?

As I research, you can use the [Windows System Management Software](https://www.pointdev.com/en/faq/faq-ideal-administration-configure-firewall-remotely-rules-windows-id-574.html) , just click on the link to see how to use the software to configure the firewall rule and download.

[image]